# Unable to serialize ReflectionDBObject (partialObject)

Tags: java, json, mongodb, rest, jackson

I'm building a REST service in Java that returns a list of datasets as JSON array and I'm using `ObjectMapper` (Jackson) to serialize the list before send back the response. The entity `Dataset` is a class that extends `ReflectionDBObject`.
Here's some code:

Dataset:

```
public class Dataset extends ReflectionDBObject {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    // other fields

    // constructor
    // getters&setters
}
```

REST:

```
public Response getDatasetsList() {
    List<Dataset> datasetsList;
    String jsonMsg;

    datasetsList = INSTANCE.getDatasetService().getDatasetsList();
    jsonMsg = INSTANCE.getObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(datasetsList);

    return Response.ok(jsonMsg, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

`INSTANCE` is my singleton class.

What I get is the following:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "551bdebb516a8100a5316125",
        "name": "a name",
        "description": "a description",
        "partialObject": false
    },
    {
        "_id": "551be03c516aedc9f999e6ff",
        "name": "metadata test name",
        "description": "metadata test description",
        "partialObject": false
    }
]
```

Is there a way to configure Jackson to remove (or just skip) the field `partialObject`? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929671/response-mongodb-objectdb-in-jersey-api-rest) provides a similar problem but the answer is not really what I'm looking for.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to show bit more of the object to see where that `partialObject` comes from. Typically you can use `@JsonIgnore` for the property; or, if you can annotate type directly, add `@JsonIgnoreType` on class `PartialObject` itself.

Comment: `partialObject` automatically comes from the extension of `ReflectionDBObject`, it's not a field of `Dataset`.

Comment: Nonetheless definition is needed to know where it comes from, so it would be useful to show that class, or similar example. But it sounds like it is just a simple additional property.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in a sub-class, it should be possible to add `@JsonIgnoredProperties` annotation in base-class to define fields to ignore, like:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "partialObject" })
public class Dataset extends ReflectionDBObject { ... }
```

which would drop the property, unless overridden by sub-class.